# How to retrive data from the couchbase lite in an app developed using cordova, ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, couchbase-lite

I am developing an App using Apache Cordova, ionic 2. I want to use Couchbase Lite for local storage in mobile. I think, able to store the data. But I am not able to retrieve the data. I used the example given in the link https://blog.couchbase.com/2016/december/data-synchronization-with-couchbase-in-ionic-2-hybrid-mobile-apps to perform the read and write operation in Couchbase local database.

Following is the code in CreateAgent.ts:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
  import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
  import { CouchbaseProvider } from "../../app/couchbase-provider";
  import { Toast } from 'ionic-native';
  import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

  @Component({
  selector: 'CreateAgent',
  templateUrl: 'CreateAgent.html'
  })
  export class CreateAgent {
  // declare the variables to hold the values
  firstName: string = "";
  lastName: string = "";
  dateofBirth: any = new Date().toISOString();
  aadharNumber: number;
  panNumber: string = "";
  eMail: any;
  userName: string="";
  mobileNumber: number;
  password: any;
  confPassword: any;
  public items: Array<any>;
  // constructor
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public couchbase: CouchbaseProvider, public zone: NgZone)
  {
  this.items = []; 
  }

  createAgent()
  {
  let userdetails = {
  "type":"agentdetails",
  "firstName": this.firstName,
  "lastName": this.lastName,
  "dateofBirth": this.dateofBirth,
  "aadharNumber":this.aadharNumber,
  "panNumber":this.panNumber,
  "mobileNumber":this.mobileNumber,
  "userName":this.userName,
  "password":this.password,
  "confPassword":this.confPassword
  };
  this.couchbase.getDatabase().createDocument(userdetails).then((result:any)=>{
  Toast.show("Agent account created.", '6000', 'center').subscribe(
  toast => {
  console.log(toast);
  }); 
  },errors=>
  {
  Toast.show("Failed to create an account for the user.", 'long', 'center').subscribe(
  toast => {
  console.log(toast);
  }); 
  });
  }

  public showAgents() {

  Toast.show("In the show method...", 'long', 'center').subscribe(
  toast => {
  console.log(toast);
  });

  setTimeout(() => {

  this.couchbase.getChangeListener().subscribe(data => {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (!data[i].hasOwnProperty("deleted") && data[i].id.indexOf("_design") === -1) {
  this.couchbase.getDatabase().getDocument(data[i].id).then((result: any) => {
  if (result.type === "agentdetails") {
  this.zone.run(() => {
  this.items.push(result);
  Toast.show("In the show method..."+result.type, 'long', 'center').subscribe(
  toast => {
  console.log(toast);
  });
  });
  }
  });
  }
  }
  }); 
  }, 100);


  this.couchbase.getDatabase().queryView("_design/todo", "items", {}).then((result: any) => {
  this.items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
  this.items.push(result.rows[i].value);
  Toast.show("In the query view..."+result.type, 'long', 'center').subscribe(
  toast => {
  console.log(toast);
  });
  }

  Toast.show("Values:"+result.rows[0].value, 'long', 'center').subscribe(
  toast => {
  console.log(toast);
  });

  }, error => {
  console.error("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
  Toast.show("Error"+JSON.stringify(error), 'long', 'center').subscribe(
  toast => {
  console.log(toast);
  });
  });
  }
  }
```

In the above program createAgent() method is used to add the details of the agent to the database. showAgents() method is used to show the details of the agents created.

Code of CreateAgent.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color ="secondary">
  <button ion-button menuToggle>
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>Net Zone</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content padding>
  <h3>Create Agent</h3>
  <ion-list>
  <!--Input box to read the first name the user -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>First Name*</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <!--Input box to read the last name the user -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Last Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lastName"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <!--Read the date of birth from the user -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Date of Birth</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD-MMM-YYYY" pickerFormat="DD-MMM-YYYY" [(ngModel)]="dateofBirth"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <!--Input box to read the Aadhar number of the user -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Aadhar Number</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="aadharNumber"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <!--Input box to read the PAN number of the user -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>PAN Number</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="panNumber"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <!--Input box to read the email address of the user -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="mail" [(ngModel)]="eMail"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <!--Input box to choose the username for the user -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Choose your Username</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userName"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <!--Input box to read the mobile number of the user -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Mobile Number</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="mobileNumber"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <!--Input box to prompt the user to enter password -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Create Password</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <!--Input box to prompt the user to enter password -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Confirm your Password</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="confPassword"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <!--Add button to create the account for the user-->
  <button ion-button secondary (click)="createAgent()">Create User Account</button>

  <button ion-button secondary (click)="showAgents()">Show Agents</button> 
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Agent's Details</ion-label> 
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{ item.firstName }}
  </ion-item>

  </ion-list> 

  </ion-content>
```

But my code is not retrieving the data from the local database.
Please help in fixing the issue. I appreciate all your help.

(Edit: adding additional code)
couchbase-provider.ts code:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http } from '@angular/http';
  import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
  import { Couchbase, Database } from "cordova-couchbase/core";
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

  declare var emit: any;

  @Injectable()
  export class CouchbaseProvider {

  private isInstantiated: boolean;
  private database: Database;
  private listener: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public constructor(public http: Http, platform: Platform) {
  if(!this.isInstantiated) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {
  (new Couchbase()).openDatabase("netzone").then(database => {
  this.database = database;
  let views = {
  items: {
  map: function(doc) {
  if(doc.type == "list" && doc.title) {
  emit(doc._id, {title: doc.title, rev: doc._rev})
  }
  }.toString()
  }
  };
  this.database.createDesignDocument("_design/todo", views);

  this.database.listen(change => {
  this.listener.emit(change.detail);
  });
  this.database.sync("http://127.0.0.1:4984/_admin", true);
  this.isInstantiated = true;
  }, error => {
  console.error(error);
  });
  });
  }
  }

  public getDatabase() {
  return this.database;
  }

  public getChangeListener(): EventEmitter<any> {
  return this.listener;
  }

  public fetch() {
  return this.database.getAllDocuments.toString();
  }
  }
```

Comment: can you add `couchbaseProvider` code?

Comment: @suraj: I added the couchbase-provider.ts code. Please check.

Comment: anything in the logs?

Comment: No errors. I used toast messages to understand the flow. The control enters the showAgents() method, but not entering the for loop inside it or the error part.

Comment: I'd recommend you try a simpler version of your code.  You're setting up a change listener with a timeout.  How are you changing the data to trigger the listener?  You have several tests in your loop.  Are you sure they're correct?  I'd really recommend starting by writing a document, then reading it back and making sure it contains what you expect.  Then build up your logic from there.

Comment: Thank you. When I did with exactly as given in the example, it worked. When I modified it, its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the data from Couchbase Light using following modifications:

Change the showAgents() method in the CreateAgents.ts file as follows:

```
public showAgents() {
//query the database using the design document and get the results
        this.chitProvider.getDatabase().queryView("_design/agentsDesign", "agents", {}).then((agentsDesignResult: any) => {
            this.agentsArray = [];
            //loop to read the documents as JSON objects and store them in the items array
            for(var i = 0; i < agentsDesignResult.rows.length; i++) {
                this.chitZone.run(() => {
                    this.agentsArray.push(agentsDesignResult.rows[i].value);
                });
 }
            }, error => {
                console.error("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    }
}
```

Change the CreateAgent.html as follows:

```
        <!--Button to show all agents account details-->
        <button ion-button secondary (click)="showAgents()">Show Agents</button>        
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Agent's Details</ion-label>            
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item *ngFor="let agt of agentsArray">
            <ion-item>{{ agt.fName }}</ion-item>
            <ion-item>{{ agt.lName }}</ion-item>
        </ion-item>
```

Note: To get multiple values, add those key value pair details to the views in the design document.